# Enabling vscan on Netapp Filer

Tags: antivirus, antivirus-integration, netapp

I want to enable **vscan** on my **Netapp Filers**. I have 2 filers dealing with different type of user data. I am presently using **Sophos Endpoint Security v10** on my windows based machines and managing the same through **Sophos Enterprise Console v4.7**. Can i register Sophos Server as vscan server on my netapp filers ?? If not what all are other possibilities ??

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, "yes." Everything you need to know is in the startup guide - available from the overview page.
http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/12148.aspx

some caveats... you're going to have to lower some security restrictions if you're running w2008 or greater. ensure the DNS server your filer is using can resolve the IP of the FQDN of your vscan server.